# Get users who has bought this product (MAGENTO)

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible in magento to filter user based on the products they have bought?
For eg.

How can I get all the users who have bought product A from category B

mysql query like

SELECT users From table users, table products .....  WHERE user has purchased product A .

Please give some ideas, I needed to make this work.
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want an actual query, you can probably do something as simple as (add additional joins to get customer information from EAV):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.customer_id FROM sales_flat_order_item i
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o ON o.entity_id = i.order_id
WHERE o.customer_id IS NOT NULL
AND i.sku = 'some-product-sku'
```

Using Magento models, this should work for you:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

/*
 * Initialize Magento. Older versions may require Mage::app() instead.
 */
Mage::init();

/**
 * Get all unique order IDs for items with a particular SKU.
 */
$orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku', 'some-product-sku')
    ->toArray(array('order_id'));

$orderIds = array_unique(array_map(
    function($orderItem) {
        return $orderItem['order_id'];
    },
    $orderItems['items']
));

/**
 * Now get all unique customers from the orders of these items.
 */
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',   array('in'  => $orderIds))
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('neq' => 'NULL'));
$orderCollection->getSelect()->group('customer_id');

/**
 * Now get a customer collection for those customers.
 */
$customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderCollection->getColumnValues('customer_id')));

/**
 * Traverse the customers like any other collection.
 */
foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    var_dump($customer->getData());
}
```

It's pretty ugly though (instantiates multiple models, executes a bunch of queries under the covers), you could probably write your own model to make this -a lot- prettier.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will do that but seems all perfect to work. And is there any website where I can find all the the tables. I mean like what is the role of every table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to base your query on orders. If you want to do it by SQL query, you have to it by the following table:

- sales_flat_quote, sales_flat_order_item to get the link between customer and product
- catalog_category_product to get the link between category and product
- catalog_product_entity to get the product id in function of the sku
- ...

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try these  models

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getCollection();

$order_items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('in' => $orders_ids))->load();
```