# Getting current product's Owner ID?

Tags: php, magento

In my shopping site, I have 100 products. From that I selected one product. How can I get the user ID for that product?

I still have to do more things with this, and this is in the seller page.

I tried this code, but it did not work.

```
<?php 
    $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
    echo $product_id; // It's displaying Product ID
    $productowner=Mage::getModel('marketplacepartner/marketplacepartner')->isCustomerProducttemp($product_id['entity_id']);
    if($productowner['productid']!=""){
        $rowsocial=Mage::getModel('marketplaceprofile/marketplaceprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
    }
?>
```

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

I have to get Owner ID of this product

Any ideas ?

Comment: Just a guess (since I'm unfamiliar with Magento), but don't forget a closing brace `}` after your $rowsocial line. In addition, did you receive any error messages? If so, please edit your question and add what the errors were.

Comment: Yeah I have closing brace } & i tried with echo $rowsocial; but no use Its showing as it is ....

Comment: You mean User ID or Product ID?

Comment: User ID (I think in DB MageuserID)

Comment: What do you mean by Product's owner ID? CustomerID?

Comment: @DRAJI I want to get Who added this product that person Id(product's Owner ID)

Comment: $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
     echo $product_id; // It's displaying Product ID   With this i'm getting Product ID ... I want Owner ID

Comment: Are you review below answer? By this we can get the User Id(CustomerID) who ordered the particular product!

Comment: yeah trying that one only ?

Comment: <?php 
 $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
 //echo $product_id;
 $userId=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId($product_id);
 echo $userId;
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

/*
* Initialize Magento. Older versions may require Mage::app() instead.
*/
Mage::init();

/*
* Get all unique order IDs for items with a particular SKU.
*/
$orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('sku', 'some-product-sku')
->toArray(array('order_id'));

$orderIds = array_unique(array_map(
function($orderItem) {
    return $orderItem['order_id'];
},
$orderItems['items']
));

/*
* Now get all unique customers from the orders of these items.
*/
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',   array('in'  => $orderIds))
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('neq' => 'NULL'));
$orderCollection->getSelect()->group('customer_id');

foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
var_dump($customer->getData());
}
```

refer this thread [Get users who has bought this product (MAGENTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510786/get-users-who-has-bought-this-product-magento)

Comment: foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
var_dump($customer->getData());
}    This is for getting customer ID list @suresh

Comment: Do you know magento? @Suresh

Comment: replace your code with some modifications of above code.in which file you put this code?

Comment: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catelog/product/view/type/default.phtml

Comment: you can get product sku by $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku(); then replace 'some-product-sku' by $sku in the above code

Comment: using this i can get current product sku " <?php echo $_product->getSku();?> " the above code is also working in another file..Here I want only Owner ID of current product that's it

Comment: By the use of product information is the only way to get your desired result. All the Best to getting result @Suresh

Answer (score 0):

You can get the seller id of a product by using a Magento SQL query like this:

(this query works for Webkul Marketplace extension, but I think you can manage to change this query to work with any other similary extension)

```
/* Get the resource model */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/* Retrieve the read connection */
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

/* Get product id */
$productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();

/* Get table name */
$table = $resource->getTableName('marketplace/product');

/* Query for user id */
$query = 'SELECT userid FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE mageproductid = '. (int)$productId . ' LIMIT 1';

/* Execute the query and store the user id in $userid */
$userid = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using marketplace extension you can try this

```
$_marketProduct=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('adminassign',array('eq'=>1))->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid','product_id');
foreach($_marketProduct as $_mp){
            $_vendorId =$_mp->getuserid();             
            $_customerDetails = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($_vendorId);
            print_r($_customerDetails);           }
```

And dont't forget to change product_id

Answer (score -1):

change `('marketplacepartner/marketplacepartner')` to `('marketplace/Userprofile')`
And `('marketplaceprofile/marketplaceprofile')` to `('marketplace/Userprofile')`

like

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
//echo $product_id; // It's displaying Product ID
$productowner=Mage::getModel('marketplace/Userprofile')>isCustomerProducttemp($product_id['entity_id']);
if($productowner['userid']!=""){
  $rowsocial=Mage::getModel('marketplace/Userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
}
$customer=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($productowner['userid']);

echo $customer->getName();
```

Comment: Do not ask questions as an answer. Leave comments instead ( if you have enough reputation )