# Magento 1.9 check if customer buys from certain category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I'm trying to check if a new order has products from certain category, and if it does pass some params to a function and execute that function. Ex:

I add 2 products in cart(one is from X category) and checkout, place the order.Now, when i finish buying the products and the order has been placed, I want to execute a function with the order_id and products_id as params.

I have serched the entire google and didn't find anything. Do you guys have any ideea how could this be created?

Comment: Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510786/get-users-who-has-bought-this-product-magento

Comment: I don't think that helps, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are aware of `event&observer`

Therefore, you can use `sales_order_place_after` event to check, like in the following example:

```
<sales_order_place_after>
   <observers>
       <b4u_order_observer>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>Mshop_B4u_Model_Observer</class>
           <method>after_order_placed</method>
       </b4u_order_observer>
   </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

Need to write the following code in `observer( mshop -> b4u -> model -> Observer.php )`

```
public static function after_order_placed($observer) {
   $event = $observer->getEvent();
   $order = $event->getOrder();
   $order_no   = (string) $order->getRealOrderId();
   $order->loadByIncrementId($order_no);
   $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

      foreach($items as $i):
         // done your code here
      endforeach;
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is the solution, let me check this