# Get users who have bought these products in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I refer to the example [Get users who have bought these products in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510786/get-users-who-has-bought-this-product-magento) , But I want to have multiple conditions with multiple products.

Suppose I have list of products having IDs 1,2,3,4,5 etc... and I want to get a list of all the customer who bought these products.

I have an interface in admin like shopping cart rule having condition **AND/OR**

My condition would like below example:

e.g:

- WHERE ( product_id = 1 **AND** product_id = 2 **AND** product_id = 3
  **AND** product_id = 4 )
- WHERE ( product_id = 1 **OR** product_id = 2 **AND** product_id = 3
  **OR** product_id = 4 )
- WHERE ( product_id = 1 **AND** product_id = 2 **OR** product_id = 3
  **AND** product_id = 4 )

But I am able to get list of all customer's email id by  WHERE product_id = 1 **OR** product_id = 2 **OR** product_id = 3 **OR** product_id = 4.

That Query is:

**SELECT DISTINCT o.customer_email FROM sales_order_item i INNER JOIN sales_order o ON o.entity_id = i.order_id WHERE((i.product_id = 1) OR (i.product_id = 2) OR (i.product_id = 3) ) GROUP BY o.customer_email**

Please suggest if anyone have this type of solution.....